# The Asymptotic formula of the generating function related with the partition of a positive integer

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, integer-partitions

This question may be duplicate with this [answer_1](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/49636/1059606) and here I referred to the same [paper](http://ramanujan.sirinudi.org/Volumes/published/ram36.pdf) by Hardy, G. H.; Ramanujan, S. referred to by [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_function_(number_theory)#cite_note-hr-16) which is referred to in answer_1.

But here I focused on the different part of the paper.

I can understand most of the proof if assuming that Theorem C in the paper is already proven. But I have some small problems.

In the paper p13, it says

> $\log g(x)=\sum_{2}^{\infty}\log \frac{1}{1-x^{\mu}}=\sum_{1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\nu}\frac{x^{2\nu}}{1-x^{\nu}}\sim \frac{1}{1-x}\sum_{1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\nu^2}$
>
> ...
>
> $\nu x^{\nu−1}(1 − x) < 1 − x^{\nu} < \nu(1 − x)$
>
> $\frac{1}{1-x}\sum \frac{x^{2\nu}}{\nu^2}<\log g(x)<\frac{1}{1-x}\sum \frac{x^{\nu+1}}{\nu^2}$

The first equation can be got by letting $f(x)=x^v$, then $f'(x)<\frac{1-f(x)}{1-x},x\to 1^{-}$. The situation where $x\to 1^{+}$ is similar.

But for the 2nd, $\sum_{2}^{\infty}\log \frac{1}{\nu(1-x)}<\log g(x)=\sum_{2}^{\infty}\log \frac{1}{1-x^{\nu}}$

Q:

How does $\sum_{2}^{\infty}\log \frac{1}{\nu(1-x)}$ becomes $\frac{1}{1-x}\sum_{\nu=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^{2\nu}}{\nu^2}$ by removing the $\log()$ function (Here I think the subscript is same as $\sum_{1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\nu}\frac{x^{2\nu}}{1-x^{\nu}}$ although the paper doesn't explicitly show it)?

**Edited**:

By Anne Bauval's comment, the removal of $\log()$ occurs when $\sum_{2}^{\infty}\log \frac{1}{1-x^{\mu}}=\sum_{1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\nu}\frac{x^{2\nu}}{1-x^{\nu}}$. This is where my doubt exists.

Comment: I am not sure to understand your question. I guess you understand that $\log g(x)=\sum_{\nu=1}^\infty\frac{x^{2\nu}}\nu\frac1{1-x^\nu}$, together with $\nu x^{\nu−1}(1−x)<1−x^\nu<\nu(1−x)$, implies
$\sum_{\nu=1}^\infty\frac{x^{2\nu}}\nu\frac1{\nu(1-x)}<\log g(x)<\sum_{\nu=1}^\infty\frac{x^{2\nu}}\nu\frac1{\nu x^{\nu−1}(1−x)}$, but you are wondering why $$\sum_{\mu=2}^{\infty}\log\frac1{1-x^\mu}=\sum_{\nu=1}^\infty\frac1\nu\frac{x^{2\nu}}{1-x^\nu}.$$ Is that it?

Comment: @AnneBauval Yes. Thanks for your comment. Sorry for lacking the clarification. I will edit my question to clarify that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\begin{align}\sum_{\mu=2}^\infty\log\frac1{1-x^\mu}&=\sum_{\mu=2}^\infty\sum_{\nu=1}^\infty\frac{x^{\nu\mu}}\nu\\&=\sum_{\nu=1}^\infty\frac1\nu\sum_{\mu=2}^\infty x^{\nu\mu}
\\&=\sum_{\nu=1}^\infty\frac1\nu\frac{x^{2\nu}}{1-x^\nu}.\end{align}$$